# Undefined Index PHPMailer Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I am using the PHPMailer Scripts to send an email from a form that a user fills out, and the user picks an image from a drop down, and the form sends the corresponding image with the email based on user selection.  So its pretty straight forward, I had it working for a little bit, then all of a sudden it stopped working, I changed nothing that I can remember.  I am also using bootstrap and DDSlick(for the dropdown).

**The Image is what comes up as undefined in the error log, every other piece of information works!**

Here is the error:

```
Undefined index: image in /home/name/website/assets/php/store-email.php on line 8
```

HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">

<div class="messages"></div>

  <div class="controls">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control popup_custom-fields" placeholder="Please enter your Name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group popup_custom-fields" id="demo-htmlselect">
                <select type="text" name="image" id="image" class="form-control " required="required">
                    <option value="select">--Select-- *</option>
                    <option value="image1" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-1.jpg">Image 1</option>
                    <option value="image2" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-2.jpg">image 2</option>
                    <option value="image3" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-3.jpg">image 3</option>
                    <option value="image4" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-4.jpg">image 4</option>
                    <option value="image5" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-5.jpg">image 5</option>
                    <option value="image6" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-6.jpg">image 6</option>
                    <option value="image7" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-7.jpg">image 7</option>
                    <option value="image8" data-imagesrc="assets/images/gallery/gallery-8.jpg">image 8</option>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control popup_custom-fields" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control popup_custom-fields" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="form_message" name="mssg" class="form-control popup_custom-fields" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send popup_custom-button" value="Send message">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
  $(function () {
$('#contact-form').validator();

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    var url = "../assets/php/store-email.php";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType:'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function (data)
        {
      var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
      var messageText = data.message;
      var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
      if (messageAlert && messageText) {
        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
        }
          }
    });
    return false;
  }
})
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $fname = $_POST['name'];
 $mail = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['mssg'];
 $tel = $_POST['tel'];
 $image = $_POST['image'];  // LINE 8

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer 
 to use SMTP
 $mail->Host = 'localhost';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
 $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to 
 connect to
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

 $mail->setFrom("email@email.com");
 // Add a recipient
 $mail->addAddress('email@email.com');               
 // Name is optional


 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email 
 format to HTML

    // Add attachments
 if ($image == 'image1') {

 $mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."assets/images/gallery/gallery-1.jpg");
}
 else if ($image == 'image2') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-2.jpg');
 }
 else if ($image == 'image3') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-3.jpg');
  }
 else if ($image == 'image4') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-4.jpg');
  }
 else if ($image == 'image5') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-5.jpg');
  }
 else if ($image == 'image6') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-6.jpg');
  }
 else if ($image == 'image7') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-7.jpg');
  }
 else if ($image == 'image8') {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-8.jpg');
  }
 else {
  $mail->addAttachment('../images/gallery/gallery-none.jpg');
   }


 $mail->Subject = 'New Message From Website!';
 $mail->Body= "$message Phone: $tel";
 $mail->AltBody = $message;
 if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
 echo 'Message has been sent';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Post the exact error you have... And there is a missing double quote `"` after `email@email.com` in the code you posted... Probably just a typo in your question...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Added

Comment: That error says the `image` index of `$_POST` isn't defined. The only thing I can see is the `type="text"` you have on the `<select>` element... It has no use for sure, but I don't know if that can be the cause...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette so the solution should be changing the type? I tried changing it to image or whatever and it didn't work still.

Comment: The `<select>` element doesn't need a `type` to be specified. Just remove it.

Comment: But I just tested on my side... And it cannot be the cause of your issue.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yea it didn't change anything

Comment: Try to remove `dataType:'json',` since the data you send isn't a json...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no change. The text and everything show in the email, just not the attachment image. But that has happened anyway

Comment: Try a `console.log( $(this).serialize() );` just before the ajax request... See if the image info is sent.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i added the console.log but I am not getting any info in the log? I put it directly above the ajax line.

Comment: `console.log()` can be seen in the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337).

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I know, I am saying there is nothing being logged.

Comment: That is strange... You are supposed to have a string like `name=me&image=image3&email=me%40me.com&tel=123456&mssg=ok` Do you have a live  link to that page ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I put the `console.log` above the `ajax{}` line, below the `var url` line. Is this the correct place? When I submit it like this, nothing is shown in the log.

Comment: Yes, that is a good place. Hey! Does the page reloads on submit?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no it does not

Comment: ok... Empty your browser's cache... And retry. That console.log not showing makes me think about caching. So the image info not sent may be caused by this too.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ok I got the log this time. `store.js:25 name=name&email=email%40email.com&tel=1234567890&mssg=test` . So it isnt even getting the image name?

Comment: So the image info really isn't sent. Do you really have the attribute `name="image"` on that `select` element ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I figured it out, it was the plugin DDslick removing my name attribute. I had to go do some more looking, I didn't even think about it until you asked that! Thank you for the help man!

Comment: Haaa... That is a problem nailed. Good. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that [DDSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) is the cause of the image not beeing sent.

Try to add this before your Ajax request:

```
$(document).find(".dd-selected-value").attr("name","image");
```

This adds the missing name attribute we were looking for to the hidden input DDSlick uses for the selected "option".
And the image info will be sent along with the others.